# Written Descriptive Logic for Target Heart Rate Equation

Tags: inequality

I work out at an Anytime Fitness Center, and a lot of the machines there have pulse indicators on them so people can reference a wall chart list to monitor if they are reaching their target heart rate. For a math project I am using a system of inequalities to graph this real life situation by referring to the shaded in areas of the graph to find an age's target zone.

This is my work thus far ...

On the chart, a person’s age must be at least 20 and at most 65, so:
x ≥ 20 
x ≤ 65 
"Y" represents heart rate.
220 is maximum heart rate
Your target rate should be between 70% and 85% of the maximum rate minus your age, so:
y ≥ 0.7(220 - x) 
y ≤ 0.85 (220 - x)

I graphed it, but there wasn't an upload option.

Anyways, I need to clearly describe the arithmetic steps logically that are needed to solve the equation to find one's target heart rate. I was hoping to get some feedback to see if this was acceptable as is?

Answer (score 1):

It seems mostly fine.  You should put an "and" between your two inequalities, or else write $0.7(220 - x) \le y \le 0.85 (220 - x)$.

Also, it's not quite right to speak of solving this "equation" because it's not an equation but rather a system of inequalities, which is satisfied by many $y$ (for any fixed $x$.)  If you want to give equations then you can say that the lower and upper heart rate targets are given by $y_\text{lower} =0.7(220 - x)$ and $y_\text{upper} =0.85(220 - x)$ respectively.

Finally I might suggest using letters like $A$ for age and $r$ for heart rate (instead of $x$ and $y$) to make it easier to follow.